# How to read input as a string in Racket

Tags: racket

How to read input as a string in Racket?

This code reads input like a line but from a current line. How to read it from a newline.

```lisp
(let ([x (read-line (current-input-port))]) x) ;read from here
;will read a \newline symbol after we hit 'enter' button
```

Comment: What does "it" refer to? What are you entering?

Comment: You can use the "mode" flag like so `(define x (read-line (current-input-port) 'return ))`, this is a very vague question but maybe it helps.

Comment: Are you entering this line of code within a REPL, or running this code within a larger program in a file? If it's in a REPL, are you referring to the 'enter' button you use to pass an expression to the REPL, or something else?

Comment: I want to read user's input like a string in program and then manipulate strings. It's more convenient than read abstract data and will convert it to string. For example. Works with (read) function because it reads from a newline, but user should use quotes to report function that input is a string

```(define (x)
   (printf "Enter a key word to quit")
   (let loop ([x (read)])
   (if (not (equal? x "quit"))
   (begin (printf "Wrong") (loop (read)))
   (display "Right. Quiting now."))))
```

Comment: This will not work  correctly if i replace (read) function to (read-line (current-input-port)) within let binding.

Comment: I don't see the problem yet... if I take your example "works with (read)" program and replace it with `(read-line)`, like this: `(define (x) (printf "Enter a key word to quit: ") (let loop ([x (read-line)]) (if (not (equal? x "quit")) (begin (printf "Wrong") (loop (read))) (display "Right. Quiting now."))))` then it allows me to enter `quit` on the same line as the prompt `Enter a key word to quit: `, just like (read) allows. Am I misunderstanding?

Comment: Oh, I might see the problem. The behavior is different in DrRacket vs on the command-line. It works in DrRacket, but breaks on a command-line REPL. I don't know what's wrong with the command-line

Comment: In this case function (x) reads a newline character after call. And it prints "wrong" immediately cuz it reads 'enter' button.
It works in that way for me in REPL.
Nevertheless thanks for trying help me.

Comment: You got ahead of me ;)